# slideToggle() has no switch parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

Page gets an AJAX *result* every now and then. *Result* is just a random boolean (true/false).

Based on the *result* certain element on the page must be shown or hidden. Notice that I cannot just `toggle()` it as I need to know whether it's true or false first.

So:

```
var result = ajax();
if (result) {
    $('#myElement').show();
}
else {
    $('#myElement').hide();
}
```

There is also a much shorter way to put this:

```
$('#myElement').toggle(ajax());
```

The [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method takes a boolean parameter called "*showOrHide*" to determine whether to show or hide the element.

Same does the [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) method. Except for some reason that parameter is called "*switch*" instead.

The question: how do I apply that parameter to [slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) or [fadeToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/)? `$('#myElement').slideToggle(ajax())` didn't work.

Or the only way I can use it is:

```
ajax() ? $('#myElement').slideDown() : $('#myElement').slideUp()
```

Comment: you also can `$('#myElement')[ajax() ? 'slideDown' : 'slideUp']()`

Comment: Also,is the ajax request a synchronous one... else it cannot return a value

Comment: Or, to make Aruns suggestion a bit more obfuscated: `$('#myElement')['slide'+ajax()?'Down':'Up']()` ... ;-)) funky, but better not to be used.

Comment: Good comments. But is the final answer that "you can't"? Any rumors if it's going to be implemented any soon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
element.toggle(1000, ajax() ? 'slideDown' : 'slideUp',  function() {
    console.log("Complete!");
});
```